# how can i vscode run python without terminal command

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to run Python in Vscode terminal without command?

current result
[image: current result]

want result
[image: want result]

I've also tried changing the run console from terminal to debug console in Launch.json, but it's not a good way because it's not set globally and don't get key input.
Is there a good way?

And apart from this question, is there any way to get the finished time print like when running Python on a sublime?
I think it's too inefficient to take a final time for each python code.

[image]

Comment: You could try to search VSCode's extension store for extension applications that can provide relevant functions.For example: AREPL; Code Runner;

Answer (score 0):

Right click "Run main.py"